# Good apps for engine vs engine matches

Tags: engines, computer-chess

I'd like to hold engine vs engine matches on my phone, and am looking for an app which could help me do this. Does Droidfish support matches between two different engines?

If not, could someone name an app available on Play Store (with a good UI) which, in addition to allowing the usual functions of game analysis and playing against engines, supports engine vs engine matches, the two engines being different?

In short, I want something like Droidfish, with an additional feature to hold engine vs engine matches, like one can on Arena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.chess&hl=en

Chess for Android has it, and it's the more or less industry standard for running engine matches on an Android mobile device.

I'm not sure if Droidfish can do it, somebody else might answer you.